# Displaying javascript variables and database values?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, output

Is there a way to display javascript variables and mysql values in a sort of label? As in say you have a letter template and there are spaces in the template where values from a database should be inserted but not in a text box. Here is a screenshot of what i am trying to explain :

The letter on the left is the template and the blue coloured text is where the database values need to be entered but in a format that would suit the letter template which will be printed and mailed out, so it couldn't be a text box, is there a way to display it in this manner?

Here is my current code :

Also is there a way to display that section of javascript in the same manner? Where it says [server date] in the template?

Comment: This is a perfect application for a [jquery templating solution](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=jquery+templates).

Comment: Look at javascript template engines like mustache or handlebars and inline edit plugins ... this should be able to get you where you want  to be

Comment: would some form of method using just echo be possible?